# Python- Mostrar datos asociados a una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

¡Buenas tardes! información sobre pistas subidas en una lista de reproducción y ayudar al usuario a saber cuál es la canción que se está reproduciendo en ese momento. Esto es lo que necesito mostrar:
[image: Reproductor]

Tengo el código medio hecho, pero no se me ocurre cómo asociar el número que introduce el usuario con el número de la canción, ya que si guardo los datos en una lista, cada dato que guarda me lo contabiliza como un ítem de la lista. También se me había ocurrido hacerlo con un diccionario ya que así podría guardar pares de datos pero tampoco se me ocurre como hacerlo. Os dejo mi código por si alguien me puede iluminar:

```
class Music():
    def add(self):
        self.name = input("Ingresa el título de la canción: ")
        self.duration = input("Ingresa la duración de la canción: ")
        self.number = int(input("Ingresa el número de canción en la lista de reproducción: "))

composition = Music()
music_list = []
i = 0
while i < 3:
    composition.add()
    music_list.append(composition.name)
    music_list.append(composition.duration)
    music_list.append(composition.number)
    i = i + 1
numero = int(input("Ingrese el número de la canción que se está reproduciendo ahora:"))
print(music_list[numero])
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución alternativa es usar tuplas.

```
(nombre, duración)
```

para representar cada canción.

Las tuplas se ponen en la lista `cancionero`, por lo que un elemento de la lista equivale a una canción (nombre y duración). La posición de la tupla en la lista es el número que la identifica. No necesitamos pedirle al usuario el número de la cancion.

El ingreso de la lista termina cuando el usuario ingresa un Enter por nombre:

```
cancionero = []
while True:
    name = input("Ingresa el título de la canción (Enter para terminar): ").strip()
    if name:
        duration = input("Ingresa la duración de la canción: ").strip()
        cancionero.append((name, duration))
    else:
        break
```

Luego de terminado el ingreso, mostramos la lista para que el usuario tenga referencia del número que identifica cada canción.

```
cuenta = 1
for cancion in cancionero:
    print(f"{cuenta}. {cancion[0]} ({cancion[1]})")
    cuenta += 1
```

En la parte reproducción, le pedimos el número de canción al usuario. No he puesto ninguna validación aquí; queda de tarea.

```
while True:
    numero = int(input("Ingrese n. canción (0 para terminar): "))
    if numero:
        numero -= 1
        print(f"{cancionero[numero][0]} ({cancionero[numero][1]})")
    else:
        break
```

produce:

```
Ingresa el título de la canción (Enter para terminar): It's a sin
Ingresa la duración de la canción: 4:59
Ingresa el título de la canción (Enter para terminar): Go West
Ingresa la duración de la canción: 4:59
Ingresa el título de la canción (Enter para terminar): Every breath you take
Ingresa la duración de la canción: 4:13
Ingresa el título de la canción (Enter para terminar): 
1. It's a sin (4:59)
2. Go West (4:59)
3. Every breath you take (4:13)
Ingrese n. canción (0 para terminar): 1
It's a sin (4:59)
Ingrese n. canción (0 para terminar): 2
Go West (4:59)
Ingrese n. canción (0 para terminar): 3
Every breath you take (4:13)
Ingrese n. canción (0 para terminar): 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @candidmoe! En este caso no es eso lo que necesito. Me dan un ejercicio y tengo que conseguir ese mismo resultado escrupulosamente. Pero también te digo que con tu código me has ayudado a entender otras cosas.

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué tal una lista de diccionarios y que el ID de la canción se maneje automáticamente?

```
[
    {'name':'Cancion1', 'duration':'mm:ss', 'artist':'Artista1'},
    {'name':'Cancion2', 'duration':'mm:ss', 'artist':'Artista2'},
    ...
]
```

Me tomé la libertad de hacer algunos cambios en los inputs, como agregar al  artista, añadir más métodos a la clase; para ilustrar qué cosas puedes hacer. El atributo `self.music_list` contiene las canciones que se van añadiendo en el método `add()`
El atributo `self.playing` controla qué **canción se está reproduciendo** en el momento.

```
class Music():
    def __init__(self):
        self.music_list = []
        self.playing = None
    
    def add(self):
        name = input("Ingresa el título de la canción: ")
        duration = input("Ingresa la duración de la canción: ")
        artist = input("Ingresa el artista: ")
        self.music_list.append({'name':name, 'duration':duration, 'artist':artist})
        
    def show_playlist(self):
        print(f'{"ID":<4} {"NOMBRE":20} {"DURACION":8} ARTISTA')
        print(f'{"--":<4} {"------":20} {"--------":8} -------')
        i = 0
        for song in self.music_list:
            print(f'{i:<4} {song["name"]:20} {song["duration"]:8} {song["artist"]}')
            i += 1
            
    def now_playing(self):
        if self.playing != None:
            song = self.music_list[self.playing]
            print(f'Reproduciendo: {song["name"]} - {song["artist"]} ({song["duration"]})')
        else:
            print('No hay canción reproduciendose')
    
    def stop_play(self):
        self.playing = None
    
    def set_play(self, number):
        if number >=0 and number < len(self.music_list):
            self.playing = number
            self.now_playing()
        else:
            print('Error, no existe cancion con ese ID')
```

Si se instancia esa clase en un objeto, se puede hacer cosas como:

```
>>> player = Music()
>>> player.add()
Ingresa el título de la canción: Zombie
Ingresa la duración de la canción: 5:06
Ingresa el artista: Cranberries
>>> player.add() # Agregamos otra canción
>>> player.add() # Agregamos otra canción
>>> 
>>> player.show_playlist()
ID   NOMBRE               DURACION ARTISTA
--   ------               -------- -------
0    Zombie               5:06     Cranberries
1    Karma Police         4:24     Radiohead
2    Everlong             4:10     Foo Fighters
>>> 
>>> player.set_play(5) # Intentar reproducir la canción No 5
Error, no existe cancion con ese ID
>>> player.set_play(1)
>>> player.now_playing() # ¿Qué canción se está reproduciendo?
Reproduciendo: Karma Police - Radiohead (4:24)
>>> player.stop()
>>> player.now_playing()
No hay canción reproduciendose
```

Creo que con eso ya puedes construir un programa principal con un menú para que el usuario seleccione las opciones. También puedes meterle más métodos a la clase, por ejemplo Siguiente canción, Canción Anterior, Borrar canción, etc.

Comment: Gracias @aeportugal! Cambiando algunas cosas de tu código casi casi lo tengo! Antes de llamar a la función set_play() le pido al usuario el número de canción y se la paso como parámetro a la función play_set() pero o se me sale de la lista o me muestra la siguiente canción.